# Text element causing Rect element to recall mouseover event

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a box that contains text, and when the user enters the box with their mouse, I play a tone (using the mouseover event). This is done using a Rect and Text element, which are siblings, both children of the svg element (I'm using d3). The mouseover event is attached to the Rect.

The problem is that when the mouse enters the Rect, it plays the tone as expected, but when they mouseover the Text inside the Rect, and then exit the Text and go back into the Rect, the mouseover event in the Rect is called again. I would like to completely ignore the mouse entering the Text so that the Rect event is only triggered once, and not again until the mouse actually leaves the rect and re-enters it again. Here is some code:

```
svg.append("rect")
          .attr('width', boxSize)
          .attr('height', boxSize)
          .attr('x', x - boxSize / 2)
          .attr('y', y - boxSize / 2)
          .on("mouseover", function() {
                  var freq = GetFrequency(innerRowNum, innerRowIndex);
                  var oscillator = startOscillator(freq, true);
           });
svg.append("text")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font", "300 " + (boxSize * 0.6) + font)
          .style("fill", "white")
          .style("pointer-events", "none")
          .text("Text");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fromElement attribute of the event, to check if the mouse was previously on the text:

```
svg.append("rect")
//...
.addEventListener("mouseover",function(evt){
   if( evt.fromElement.id != "text-id" ){
      var freq = GetFrequency(innerRowNum, innerRowIndex);
      var oscillator = startOscillator(freq, true);
   }
});
```

but fromElement does not seem to be supported by Firefox. See http://help.dottoro.com/ljjqfjbs.php

You could also define listen to mouseover on the parent and check if the mouse is inside the rect.

**edit**

Another option is to use a flag to ensure that the sound is not executed on a mouseover except initially or after moving out the rect. 
http://jsfiddle.net/nhx0o33t/2/